# Jacobi theta with a matrix

Tags: matrix-calculus, gaussian-integral, theta-functions

I would like to evaluate
$$
\sum_{q_1 = -\infty}^{\infty} \cdots \sum_{q_N = -\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\sum_{j}\sum_{k} q_{k} A_{kj} q_{j}}
$$
with $A$ a real $N\times N$ symmetric matrix.

I know how to compute this when $q$ is continuous (the sum is an integral), and I know how to compute this when $A$ is a scalar (a $1\times 1$, this leads to the Jacobi theta), but If I try to diagonalize $A$, I end up with a transformation for the $q$s that I don't know how to write down in terms of a sum.  The transformed $q$s, $q' = O^{T}q$, are linear combinations of the $q$s, and I don't know what the analogous Jacobian-like object would be for summation (in place of integration).  Thanks.

Comment: Are your indices right in that expression?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I think so, is it misleading that I doubled up on $i$?  I can make it a different letter.

Comment: @knives The indices are very confusing to me. Does $\prod_i \sum_{q_i}$ actually mean $\sum_{q_1} \ldots \sum_{q_N}$ ?

Comment: @Startwearingpurple Exactly.  It is a sum over each of the $q$s.  I guess this is causing trouble.  I'll try and be more explicit, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be expressed in terms of elementary (or Jacobi theta) functions: in fact the series
$$\Theta\left(\mathbf z | \Omega\right)=\sum_{\mathbf q\in\mathbb Z^N}e^{\pi i \mathbf q\cdot \Omega\cdot \mathbf q+2\pi i \mathbf q \cdot \mathbf z}$$
is a multidimensional generalization of the Jacobi theta function called [Riemann theta function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/21.2). Your case corresponds to setting $\mathbf z=\mathbf 0$, $\Omega=\frac{iA}{\pi}$, i.e. to Riemann theta constants.

For the numerical evaluation, you may have a look at [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/nlin/0206009).

Comment: The eigenvalues of $A$ are necessarily real, but not positive definite, this ruins its applicability doesn't it?

Comment: @kηives If $A$ has non-positive eigenvalues, your sum does not converge.

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: Do you know if the Riemann theta has a similar property? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobisImaginaryTransformation.html

Comment: @kηives Yes,,one has something like $\Theta \left( (C\Omega + D )^{-T} \mathbf z | \left( A\Omega +B\right) \left( C\Omega +D \right)^{-1} \right) \sim \Theta (\mathbf z | \mathbf \Omega)$ up to some elementary prefactors for any $2N\times 2N$ matrix $ \left( \begin{array}{cc} A & B \\ C & D \end{array}\right) \in Sp(2N,\mathbb Z )$. The usual Jacobi imaginary transformation corresponds to $N=1$ and $A=D=0$, $B=-C=1$. You can find more details in Mumford's book on theta functions.